# Codecademy: Nested Lists

Tags: html, list

I'm doing a lesson on Codecademy about nested lists in html.

My code is as follows:

```
<ul>
<li>Work? I am currently unemployed.
  Here's a list of things that I have
  done though:

  <ol>
    <li>Farm Hand</li>
    <li>Excersize Rider</li>
    <li>Curator's Assistant</li>
    <li>Teaching Assistant</li>
    <li>Telephone Operator</li>
  </ol>

</li>
<li>Education? I have dropped out of the
  following institutions:

  <ol>
    <li>
      Highschool (I did complete all
      courses and receive credit)
    </li>
    <li>
      College (I withdrew for
      medical reasons)
    </li>
  </ol>

</li>
<li>Interests? Here are a select few:

  <ol>
    <li>Running</li>
    <li>Martial arts</li>
    <li>Equestrian activities</li>
    <li>Video games</li>
  </ol>

</li>
<li>Favorite Quotes

  <ol>
    <li>"This was a triumph"</li>
    <li>
      "It's not safe to go alone, 
      here, take this!"
    </li>
    <li>
      "Our princess is in
      another castle!"
    </li>
  </ol>

</li>
</ul>
```

However, the lesson throws the following error when I try to submit this code:

> Oops, try again. Make sure you have at least one unordered list inside your unordered list of profile sections!

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `ol` is a ordered list.

Comment: You don’t describe or cite the specific assignment. We might infer that from the error message, but your comment to the answer you approved means that either the assignment was different or you misunderstood it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error,

> Oops, try again. Make sure you have at least one unordered list inside your unordered list of profile sections!

you need one [unordered list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul) inside your unordered list of profile sections. Currently, all of your internal lists are [ordered lists](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol) (`<ol>`). Try turning one of them into a `<ul>`.



For example, this should match your error desciption:

```
<ul>
<li>Work? I am currently unemployed.
  Here's a list of things that I have
  done though:

  <ul>  <!--(Unordered List!)-->
    <li>Farm Hand</li>
    <li>Excersize Rider</li>
    <li>Curator's Assistant</li>
    <li>Teaching Assistant</li>
    <li>Telephone Operator</li>
  </ul>

</li>
<li>Education? I have dropped out of the
  following institutions:

  <ol>
    <li>
      Highschool (I did complete all
      courses and receive credit)
    </li>
    <li>
      College (I withdrew for
      medical reasons)
    </li>
  </ol>

</li>
<li>Interests? Here are a select few:

  <ol>
    <li>Running</li>
    <li>Martial arts</li>
    <li>Equestrian activities</li>
    <li>Video games</li>
  </ol>

</li>
<li>Favorite Quotes

  <ol>
    <li>"This was a triumph"</li>
    <li>
      "It's not safe to go alone, 
      here, take this!"
    </li>
    <li>
      "Our princess is in
      another castle!"
    </li>
  </ol>

</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Okay thanks! I was trying to do what the assignment said, but the error clearly indicates that they were looking for something else...